# SELECT INTO OUTFILE isn't working?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep trying to run this function and I have rewritten it in all ways possible, but I cannot get it work:

```
public function backup($location) {
    $database = 'logindb';

    $backup = $location.'/'.$database.'_backup_'.date('Y').'_'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'.sql';

    $sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup' FROM users";

    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)){
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo $stmt->error();    
        }
        $stmt->close();
        echo 'done';
    } else {
        echo 'Error';   
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what could be wrong ?

Comment: if you don't say which is the error how we can help?

Comment: I don't get any errors, I run it and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type ps-Af to see what is the username of your webserver (usually apache or httpd)
Then type chown -R apache:apache  (or httpd respactively)  in one folder up 
your backup directory
Then type chmod u+w  
I think that since webserver tries to write the file, it must have write permissions

Comment: outfile runs on mysql not on application level. That means it's mysql permission not apache. You can try it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

mysql user must have write access to the path in $backup

Comment: I'm running the script on a localhost ( XAAMP ), I think I have the write access as root user.

Comment: mysql user not root user. as root do the following:
chown -R mysql:mysql [ your backup directory ]

Comment: and how do I know if it has ?